# How to generate arbitrary instances of a simple type for quickcheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have a simple type definition:

```
data Cell = Cell {
    x       :: Int,
    y       :: Int
  } deriving (Show)
```

I can't use `Cell` as an input to a quickcheck property, presumably because quickcheck doesn't know how to generate Cell values.

My understanding is that I need to make Cell an instance of the `Arbitrary` typeclass.

How do I do that, for example, if I'd like Cell to be generated with random positive values for x and y?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39689127/69663  if you don't feel like writing instances.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Writing an instance of `Arbitrary` for your data type is easy. You just have to implement the `arbitrary` function, which should return a `Gen Cell`. The simplest way to do this is to make use of existing `Arbitrary` instances and also note that `Gen` is a monad, so we can use `do`-notation:

```
instance Arbitrary Cell where
   arbitrary = do
     Positive x <- arbitrary
     Positive y <- arbitrary
     return $ Cell x y
```

Alternatively, generators can often be written elegantly using operators from `Control.Applicative`:

```
instance Arbitrary Cell where
   arbitrary = Cell <$> pos <*> pos
     where pos = getPositive <$> arbitrary  -- getPositive requires QC >= 2.5
```

Here, I've also made use of the `Positive` modifier from [Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/latest/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Modifiers.html) to ensure that we only generate positive integers.

For writing more complex generators, have a look at the various generators from [Test.QuickCheck.Gen](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.6/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html).

Comment: This is where I would *really* like to use Applicative syntax instead.

Comment: Also, do consider writing an implementation for `shrink`. Less important here, perhaps, but saves so much effort for some cases.

Answer (score 16):

You can generate an `Arbitrary` instance doing the same using TemplateHaskell and [derive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/derive) package:

```
import Data.DeriveTH

derive makeArbitrary ''Cell
```

Comment: You should mention where Data.DeriveTH comes from.